# RSpec test doesn't work but it's works great in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I don't know what I'm doing wrong so please help me out.

So as the title says all works great in the browser. So I guess it's the spec I'm not able to get right.

I've rewrote code in my helpers, controllers and spec several times to.

Here's my spec for now:

```
describe "visit as admin" do
    before do
      sign_in admin
      visit organization_users_path # row 20 of users_controller_spec
    end
    it "should display right page" do
      page.should have_selector('title', text: "Users") 
    end
  end
```

When i run it i get:

```
1) Organization::UsersController visit as admin should display right page
     Failure/Error: visit organization_users_path
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `users' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/organization/users_controller.rb:5:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/organization/users_controller_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And heres my controller and helper:

```
# helper
def current_organization
  @current_organization ||= current_user.organization
end

def admin_user
  unless current_user.admin?
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

#controller
class Organization::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :admin_user

  def index
    @users = current_organization.users
  end
end
```

Edit 1: From `rake routes`:

```
organization_users GET    /organization/users(.:format)          organization/users#index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like in the `index` function for the controller: `current_organization` is `nil`.

Please make sure this helper is returning a valid object:

```
def current_organization
  @current_organization ||= current_user.organization
  raise @current_organization.inspect # <--- use this to inspect this value and delete afterwards
end
```

Comment: This one lead me into right directions. I did not create any organization in my spec becouse i did not think I needed to. I did just want to check the title ;) So when i did create the organization it all worked great. The page did work whitout user assigned to one so thought i didn't need to assign the user.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that the `current_organisation` is nil, and that seems logical as it's loaded through the current_user which is nil in your context.

You can take a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara to log a user in the tests.

But don't forget to log a user which as an organization in your setup so the current_organization helper doesn't return nil

EDIT : I'm guessing you're using devise for login, if this is not the case, please let us know, what you're using for authentication

Comment: Not using any specifik gem for auth.

Comment: In that case, you could simply stub the current_user helper to return a user instead of nil